# Securing web method on a public web app

Tags: asp.net, ajax, api, security, mobile

I have a public web app that calls ASP.NET web method in an ASMX file, located in the same site folder in IIS. But, to prevent bots to ping the service directly, we'd like to secure the API so that only our HTML 5 client page can access it. Do you have a suggestion on how should I implement this kind of thing ? Not too much, just a simple mechanism that won't take a week of testing please. Doesn't have to be a 100% full proof method since it is public data and the API just pumps data out, not inserting anything. Just something to limit possibilities of DDOS attack on the API.

Comment: Hello! one question, the client must be logged to call your api methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I've tackled this in the past is with a custom header.

Essentially if your web page is using some form of AJAX call to call back to your services layer, then you can use something like:

xhr.setRequestHeader('custom-header', 'value');

where 'xhr' is an XML Http request that you've built in Javascript

of course you could also take the much easier route of just adding a parameter to your calls query string, EG:

in your ajax call, request:

http://my.services/service.asmx?somesecretkey=foobar

instead of just

http://my.services/service.asmx

Then you can just use the request's query string collection server side to see if it's present or not, and refuse the connection if it's not.

You could even go so far as providing some seed value in the data passed to the page in the first place, then use that seed value to create a unique value (one the server can also calculate) that is returned back in your request to the server.

Doing it that way would provide a slightly higher level of security, as the values would be semi random and not easy for a bot to guess.

Bear in mind also, that if you control the calling page, and you are doing this by ajax, you can also put this key in your post variables collection too so it doesn't have to be visible in the get request.